# How can I get Kendo calendar object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, calendar, kendo-mobile

Here I am trying to add swipe functionality to the Kendo calendar. I am unable to retrieve the Kendo calendar object. How I can retrieve the Kendo calendar object in the controller?

**view page**:

```
<div class="demo-section k-content" >
    <div>
        <kendo-calendar ng-model="datestring" style="width: 100%;"  ng-click="valuefunction(datestring,dateObject)" k-enable-swipe="true" k-on- swipe="myTouch.swipe(kendoEvent)" k-ng-model="dateObject"></kendo-calendar>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**:

```
$scope.myTouch = {
    swipe: function(e) 
    {  
        if(e.direction=="left")
        {
            (here i need to access kendo calendarobject).navigateToFuture();
        }
        else if(e.direction=="right")
        {
            (here i need to access kendo calendarobject).navigateToPast(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: This this link: [http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/calendar/angular](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/calendar/angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

view page :

`<div class="demo-section k-content" >
        <div>
            <kendo-calendar kendo-touch  ng-model="datestring"  style="width: 100%;" k-rebind="datestring" ng-click="valuefunction(datestring)" k-enable-swipe="true"  k-on-swipe="myTouch(kendoEvent,datestring)" ></kendo-calendar>
        </div> 
    </div>`

controller page

$scope.myTouch = function(e, datestring) {

```
if (e.direction == "left") {

  datestring.setDate(datestring.getDate() + 30);
  $scope.datestring = datestring;
  // $scope.month=datestring;
  console.log(datestring);
  console.log('swipeleft');
}

// $scope.datestring.navigateToFuture();
else if (e.direction == "right") {

  datestring.setDate(datestring.getDate() - 30);
  $scope.datestring = datestring;
  // $scope.month=datestring;
  console.log(datestring);
  console.log('swiperight');
}
```

};